# How can I have my view presented in a modal sheet in the SwiftUI preview?

Tags: swiftui

I am developing a SwiftUI view that will be presented as a modal sheet, and I would like the preview to reflect that. (Modal sheets aren’t as tall as full-screen views, and—more significantly—no notch or island intrudes into the top of a sheet.) Is it possible to have the SwiftUI preview show my view in a sheet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the `.sheet()` modifier, just as if you were presenting the view from your “real” code:

```swift
static var previews: some View {
    Color.clear
        .sheet(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
            MyView()
        }
}
```

This has the slight disadvantage that the sheet animates in every time your preview reloads. Otherwise, though, it works well to show how your view will look and behave.